# Why will my app not open the SMS message composer?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, sms, mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller

I am trying to get my app to open the SMS message composer and I get this weird error when the app tries to launch the composer:

> Error while [CKSMSComposeRemoteViewController: 0x1ddc2900] waiting for service to execute viewWillAppear: Error Domain=XPCObjectsErrorDomain Code=2 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (XPCObjectsErrorDomain error 2.)"

I have never seen any error remotely close to this, and I have no idea why I am getting it as I found almost the same code online, tried it, and it worked.

What is wrong with my code, and what does this error mean?

Here is my code:

```
if ([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText]) {
            NSLog(@"can send text");
            MFMessageComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];
            picker.messageComposeDelegate = self;
            picker.recipients = [stringComponents objectAtIndex:1];
            picker.body = [stringComponents objectAtIndex:2];
            [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
            NSLog(@"%@", picker.recipients);
            NSLog(@"%@", picker.body);
        }
```

When building the above code, I get no error messages in Xcode, and I am able to load the screen to the point that I want to open the message composer, then it crashes and shows the message.  Thank you for your response in advanced.

Comment: did you include the MessagingUI.Framework ? and the header #import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>  ?

Comment: Yes I did, and I made sure to declare the `MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate` as well.